# How to go about matching first and last name to an email in Python scraper

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm very new to python and have been getting help from peers with developing this program. I essentially have a very unrefined, dynamic scraper, that pulls emails from a given URL.

I've been considering how I would go about matching up a first/last name to the email address, and come up with the idea of matching any 4+ consecutive characters before the '@' in an email to another element on the web page, under the assumption that most business's use at least some portion of first/last name in the creation of the email. I also decided to go with 4 characters to avoid any mix ups that might occur at 3+ characters, as I don't feel this is specific enough.

I hope this isn't too general of a question, I'm just unsure where to start.

Most of what I have found while pondering this question has been based on splitting the email and using regex to match, but I'm unsure if this will work on the page itself/how to implement.

```
import urllib.request,re
f = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.sampleurl.com")
s = f.read().decode('utf-8')
print(re.findall(r"\+\d{2}\s?0?\d{10}",s))
print(re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",s))
```

This a very basic version of a much larger program, but it is most of the inner workings. It returns email and phone number properly based on the given URL.

```
from email_split import email_split
import urllib.request,re

#Find Emails
f = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.sampleurl.com/")
s = f.read().decode('utf-8')
e = (re.findall(r"[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}",s))

emails = []

for x in e:
    emails.append(str(x))

#Split Email
email = email_split(x)

str = email.local
match = re.search(r'([\w.-]+)', str)
if match:
    print match.group()
```

Comment: it's good practice to accept a solution if it fits your need, or at least let people know that you have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sort of a general question, but I thought of this right away. I'm sort of thinking this would be a 3 step process:

1) extract the names on the website. I haven't used it, but sounds like you could use [spaCy](https://spacy.io/) to pull out `name` entities. Then store those in some type of list of names.

2) extract all the email addresses on the site and store those in a list of email addresses.

3) Then use `fuzzywuzzy` to iterate through the names and find matches to an email address [sample of fuzzywuzzy](https://www.neudesic.com/blog/fuzzywuzzy-using-python/)

Without having a specific website to try this on, it's just in theory, and I created a sample list to sort of show what I'm thinking:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process

names = ['John A. Smith', 'Michael Jordan', 'James Thomas', 'Bradley Cooper']

emails = ["jasmith@foo.com", "john.smith@bar.com", "jthomas@foobar.com", "bradc@company.com"]
email_users = [ x.split('@')[0] for x in emails ]

email_dict = dict(zip(email_users, emails))

for name in names:
    matches = process.extract(name, email_users, limit=3)
    print ('%s: ' %name)
    for each in matches:
        if each[1] >= 70:
            print ('\t%-20s - Score: %s' %(email_dict[each[0]], each[1]))
        else:
            continue
```

**Output:**

```
John A. Smith: 
        john.smith@bar.com   - Score: 95
        jasmith@foo.com      - Score: 70
Michael Jordan: 
James Thomas: 
        jthomas@foobar.com   - Score: 77
Bradley Cooper: 
        bradc@company.com    - Score: 72
```